# Detect IE9 without feature detection

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, browser-detection

So I need to detect IE 9. I know I should really use [feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944169/detecting-ie-using-jquery/1944186#1944186) but I don't know *what feature is causing my issue* all I know is that Ie 9 is causing me issues.

I've got a work around to my issue (for those interested I asked a question about the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982505/modal-dialog-missing-image-on-form-submit-ie9) but really, it is irrelevant).

Now I want to implement this <strike>hack</strike> fix only for IE9 as this is what's causing me the headache.

So how is the best way to detect IE 9?

Comment: IE conditional comments...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: $.browser has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and was removed in 1.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These IE conditionals will give you a CSS class to key-off-of:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie10 lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="lt-ie10" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

So if you only care about IE9, you could do:

```
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

Or, to keep with convention:

```
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="lt-ie10" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

Then your JS (and CSS) could key off the HTML.lt-ie10 selector:

```
 if ($('HTML.lt-ie10').length) {
     //this is IE9 and older
 }
 else {
     //this is not IE9 and older (so it could be Chrome, or Safari or IE10, etc)
 }
```

Comment: Here is more info on how to use them:
http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html

Comment: Might as well make that last one `<!--[if IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->`, as IE10 will treat the conditional comments as every other non-IE browser would. ;)

Comment: I found this useful to help me with the syntax btw: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery (1.8 or lower)

```
if ( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 9) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: The `browser` property was deprecated ages ago and was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: didn't realise this had a version as well as a msie flag!

Comment: @JamesAllardice, I didn't realise, why would they do that!

Comment: as @JamesAllardice, said I was also wary of tying myself into old versions of Jquery!

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, because you really should be doing feature detection instead of browser version sniffing